# How Often to Check For Hardware Errors/Failure?

Tags: hardware-failure, ubuntu-server

I just discovered this great post: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-server-predicting-hardware-failure.html

and have been wondering how frequently is typical to check for failed/failing hardware?  I'd like to as early as possible if something goes out but also don't want to suck up all the computation power of the machine just to have the machine check itself.  I have a modified version of the suggested line in a shell script, CheckHardware.zsh that I want to add as a cronjob:

```
#!/bin/zsh
[ $(grep -c "hardware error" /var/log/mcelog) -gt 0 ] && echo "Hardware Error Found On $(hostname) @ $(date)" | ssmtp administrator@example.com
```

I was also unclear if the command line utility (mcelog) had to be run as a cronjob very frequently as well?  That is, do I have to have two cronjobs?  run mcelog and then check the mcelog file for any contents with "hardware error"?

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think much better than checking in some interval is getting alerted if something breaks.

One popular tool for this is for example http://nagios.org/ and if you google there are many more.

These tools can send you email alerts when there is something wrong. So you could for example use the script that you posted and with some little modification integrate it to nagios to make nagios alert you if the script detects a problem.